# Use data in Spark Dataframe column as condition or input in another column expression

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an operation that I want to perform within PySpark 2.0 that would be easy to perform as a `df.rdd.map`, but since I would prefer to stay inside the Dataframe execution engine for performance reasons, I want to find a way to do this using Dataframe operations only.

The operation, in RDD-style, is something like this:

```
def precision_formatter(row):
    formatter = "%.{}f".format(row.precision)
    return row + [formatter % row.amount_raw / 10 ** row.precision]
df = df.rdd.map(precision_formatter)
```

Basically, I have a column that tells me, for each row, what the precision for my string formatting operation should be, and I want to selectively format the 'amount_raw' column as a string depending on that precision.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to use the contents of one or more columns as input to another Column operation. The closest I can come is suggesting the use of `Column.when` with an externally-defined set of boolean operations that correspond to the set of possible boolean conditions/cases within the column or columns.

In this specific case, for instance, if you can obtain (or better yet, already have) all possible values of `row.precision`, then you can iterate over that set and apply a `Column.when` operation for each value in the set. I believe this set can be obtained with `df.select('precision').distinct().collect()`.

Because the `pyspark.sql.functions.when` and `Column.when` operations themselves return a `Column` object, you can iterate over the items in the set (however it was obtained) and keep 'appending' `when` operations to each other programmatically until you have exhausted the set:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as PSF

def format_amounts_with_precision(df, all_precisions_set):
    amt_col = PSF.when(df['precision'] == 0, df['amount_raw'].cast(StringType()))
    for precision in all_precisions_set:
        if precision != 0:  # this is a messy way of having a base case above
            fmt_str = '%.{}f'.format(precision)
            amt_col = amt_col.when(df['precision'] == precision,
                           PSF.format_string(fmt_str, df['amount_raw'] / 10 ** precision)

    return df.withColumn('amount', amt_col)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a python UDF.  They can take as many input values (values from columns of a Row) and spit out a single output value.  It would look something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import types as T, functions as F
from pyspark.sql.function import udf, col

# Create example data frame
schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField('precision', T.IntegerType(), False),
    T.StructField('value', T.FloatType(), False)
])

data = [
    (1, 0.123456),
    (2, 0.123456),
    (3, 0.123456)
]

rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

# Define UDF and apply it
def format_func(precision, value):
    format_str = "{:." + str(precision) + "f}"
    return format_str.format(value)

format_udf = F.udf(format_func, T.StringType())

new_df = df.withColumn('formatted', format_udf('precision', 'value'))
new_df.show()
```

Also, if instead of the column precision value you wanted to use a global one, you could use the lit(..) function when you call it like this:

```
new_df = df.withColumn('formatted', format_udf(F.lit(2), 'value'))
```